# Table design flaw. How to design it properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have thse tables:

Table `Source`:

```
IdSource (PK)
IdCurrentVersion (FK from TableSourceVersions.IdSourceVersion) updated when a new version appears
Value
```

Table `SourceVersions`:

```
IdSourceVersion (PK)
IdSource (FK)
Value
```

These two tables describe a product definition and its versions.

Now I have two other tables which can have any combination of definition and versions (something like these two tables above):

```
TableX
--------------------
IdX (PK)
IdSource

TableXVersions
--------------------
IdVersion (PK)
IdX (FK)
IdSourceVersion
```

Generally the idea is that Table X and TableXVersion could have different versions of both (IdSource and IdSourceVersion).

The solution for table design eludes me.

I don't know how to save integrity of both (`IdSource` and `IdSourceVersion`)
in two tables: `TableX` and `TableXVersions`, taking into account that `TableX` must have definition defined (`idSource`) and `tableXVersion` one of many `IdSourceVersion`.

That design is flawed because I can have `IdSource` in master and version from another definition ....

Thanks for any help ...

Comment: Use consistent naming.  What is master?

Comment: @Blam Sorry, should be: That design is flawed because I can have IdSource in TableX and version from another definition in TableXVersions. generally I need to track definion and various versions in two another table and need to maintance the integrity.

Comment: List the FK and to which tables.  How does TableXVersions relate to Source and SourceVersion tables?  And edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the flaw in the design is storing `IDCurrentVersion` against the table `Source`, I would approach this in one of two ways.

**1. Use a view to calculate current version**

If the current version is always the latest version in `TableSourceVersions`, then I assume you have a date field to define latest, then I would create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.LatestTableSourceVersions
AS
    SELECT  IDSourceVersion,
            IDSource,
            Value,
            CreatedDate
    FROM    (   SELECT  IDSourceVersion,
                        IDSource,
                        Value,
                        CreatedDate,
                        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IDSource ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC)
                FROM    TableSourceVersions
            ) AS tsv
    WHERE   RowNum = 1;
GO
```

This means you don't need to update `Source` for each new version, the view is kept up to date automatically.

**2. Use a flag to mark the current version**

If you can't calculate the current version in such a simplistic manner, then I would still not store current version in `Source`, I would add a bit field to `TableSourceVersions` to mark the current version, e.g. `IsCurrent`.

```
ALTER TABLE TableSourceVersions ADD IsCurrent BIT;
```

You can make sure there is just one current version per `IdSource` with a unique filtered index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_TableSourceVersions__IDSource 
    ON TableSourceVersions (IDSource)
    WHERE IsCurrent = 1;
```

---

However, to actually answer your question, with your current table structure you can maintain integrity by creating a unique index on `TableSourceVersions`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_TableSourceVersions__IDSourceVersion_IDSource
    ON TableSourceVersions (IDSourceVersion, IDSource);
```

Then rather than having a foreign key from `IdCurrentVersion` to `IdSourceVersion`, you can make the foreign key reference both columns ensuring a valid version is selected:

```
ALTER TABLE [Source] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Source__IdCurrentVersion_IDSource
    FOREIGN KEY (IdCurrentVersion, IDSource)
    REFERENCES TableSourceVersions (IDSourceVersion, IDSource);
```

Comment: Thanks, with that IsCurrent it is a nice solution, however the second part of my question relates to additional two tables which have source id and versions in detail tables (look at tables: TableX and TablexVersions). Just don't get your second answer ... Please explain to me

Comment: In TableX I store the definition. TableXVersions can store different version for a definition. Different combinations per IdX

Comment: Sorry, I missed half the question! The way Blam has suggested is the simplest, and probably cheapest way that you can maintain integrity, i.e. by adding `IdSource` to `TableXVersions`.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to repeat IdSource

```
TableX
--------------------
IdX      (PK)
IdSource (PK)    (FK)

TableXVersions
--------------------
IdVersion (PK)
IdX      (FK1)
IdSource (FK1)  (FK2) 
IdSourceVersion (FK2)
```

Another option is just no tableX

And that is table design not T-SQL design.  T-SQL is the query language.

Comment: Hmm What about repeated IdSource in TableXVersion? I cannot crfate FK (TableX and TableXVersion, column: IdSource) unless it is a part of PK or UniqueIndex. FK2 I assume would get from SourceVersions, right?

Comment: What is stopping you from making it part of the PK on TableX?

Comment: Well, I assumed at the beginning that IdSource might be null, however I will have to reconsider the design ...

Comment: Even if IdSource can be null you can do this with a Unique constraint.